# Your question may be better elsewhere prompt before asking question

Tags: discussion

Here's an idea: Instead of recommending that the questions be moved to another SO site and creating new sites to match each need, users should be redirected (verbally) off of Stack Overflow to another site, and to come back if they have a question that fits the terms of use.

Here's the problem - we are so used to Stack Overflow (sites) that we don't want to go anywhere else. It seems that there should be something in the SO world of sites for my stupid opinionated question or tool request, but only those well versed in SO rules actually know that. And even knowing that, like I said, we still have an urge to post on SO, just because the thought wants to be posted.

So - on the ask a question page, for applicable sites, I suggest that it be asked alongside "Questions that may already have your answer", "maybe your post does not belong on Stack Overflow, maybe it belongs on [Yahoo! answers](http://answers.yahoo.com) or [Quora](http://www.quora.com)?" Here are the types of things that don't belong on SO, but would belong there - career related questions, tool requests, general philosophical questions (even programming related), etc.

Certainly I'd rather that SO took every question in some capacity, but seeing as it is resolved not to do so, the most effective way to handle this will be to alert the user that the question will be better handled somewhere else. Really, it has not yet occurred to me until now to touch these sites, owing to their "dirty" UI, in my opinion, and owing to that I like SO.

Since SO has yet resolved not to compete, they should be encouraging users to leave and return when they have have a suitable question. If you just downvote and close their posts, and ban them it will be far less effective and more offensive than simply encouraging them to leave of their own accord (and return of course).

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title to "Your question may be better elsewhere prompt before asking question".

Comment: Sure. I've changed.

Comment: The -1 probably means disagreement - i.e. people think it's a bad idea.

Comment: 'maybe your post does not belong on Stack Overflow, maybe it belongs in /dev/null'

Comment: @Tim: Lol way to reinforce his sentiment - "Disagreement already. Why even bother with stack overflow..." sounds about right.

Answer (score 10):

I see no reason for StackOverflow to make advertisements for other sites. Can't you just search yourself if you need another site to answer your question?

The help center is quite clear in which topics are allowed. Posting here 'because you always post all your programming related questions on StackOverflow' is not a good excuse.

Comment: I guess the argument here is that promoting another site would improve this site...

Comment: That is a wrong assumption @tim

Comment: I'm unconvinced by that to be honest... I think that hinting to people that SE isn't the place for everything may work.

Comment: True, which it does now. But why send people to Quora?

Comment: Because people are people not robots. They don't look at the rules and say "oh I'm not allowed to post here. Ahh well, my question will go un answered". Instead they say "They say not to post, but I may as well try as I want an answer...". If we said "SE is a great site but not for all questions. If you question is XYZ, Quora will be better suited to it" then people will think "I can't post here, but I will ask on the better site and get a better answer!"